# How to make Flask-SQLAlchemy automatically rollback the session if an exception is raised?

Tags: python, flask, transactions, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to setup an app built with `Flask-SQLAlchemy` to rollback all changes done to the database if the view raises an exception that bubbles outside the view code (i.e. not catched inside).

I'd like it to work even if some objects are flushed to the database in subtransactions, either automatically or directly via `session.commit()`.

Something similar to [Django's transaction request wrapping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests).

Comment: what do you mean, like in a celery task or something?

Comment: No, inside a Flask app. I want the transaction rolled back automatically if there is an uncatched exception in the view code while responding to a request.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    if exception:
        db.session.rollback()
    db.session.remove()
```

Have a look [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_request) for teardown_request info. You might need to set the `PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION` config variable if you are in debug mode.

Comment: I already set the above config to True.. But it still fails to rollback.

Comment: What are the reasons for not doing this?

Comment: Flask-SQLALchemy has an option `SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN ` Ref: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/f465142ea1643b4f0fe50540780ef9a6bf2c7e53/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L803 While I always suggested that you should commit on teardown_request

Comment: The `SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN` setting has been deprecated in v2.4.3. See https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/issues/216

Comment: Is it a good idea to do this automatically? If yes, why isn't this the default? Why/when would you want to not rollback?

Comment: I've just seen that I've asked this question already in 2017 (4 years ago!). Time to open a dedicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68312409/562769

Answer (score 8):

You could include the rollback in a custom error handler...

```
@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_error(error):
    db.session.rollback()
    return render_template('500.html'), 500
```

See [here](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-error-handling/page/4) under the Custom Error Pages section.

Comment: This method works more consistently for me than the accepted answer. Upon exception, the accepted solution does not seem to actually remove the session, which causes failures on subsequent incoming requests and block the web server.

Comment: Indeed, the accepted solution seems to be doing something else - rolling back on app tear down rather than on exception!

Comment: It's missing the session removal (`db.session.remove()`), as seen in the @reptilicus answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33284980/2340939

Comment: @user2340939 I had a look at https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html and it appears ```db.session.remove()``` will also ```rollback()``` the session. Would you propose replacing ```rollback()``` with ```remove()```? Or alternatively, would a ```rollback()``` and ```close()``` be better?

Comment: Good find. Based on the documentation, `close()` only ends, i.e. ignores, doesn't commit the transaction if one is in progress, while `remove()` actually rolls back such transaction. If that's true, then `remove()` is better since it's more DRY. But I'm suspecting the documentation mistakenly says `transactions specifically are rolled back`, because I think `remove()` handles potentially opened transaction the same as `close()`. Not sure though!

Answer (score 8):

The most reliable solution that has worked for me, inspired by [dduffy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62898299/616632), is to attach an errorhandler that specifically catches SQLAlchemy exceptions and issue a rollback.

```
from sqlalchemy import exc
@app.errorhandler(exc.SQLAlchemyError)
def handle_db_exceptions(error):
    #log the error: app.logger.error(error)
    db.session.rollback()
```

The `@app.teardown_request` hook approach didn't seem to fix the db connection that was in a bad state in time before it was reused by later requests pulling it from the db connection pool. The `errorhandler` approach catches the connection before it is reused, and by limiting it in scope to the class of errors raised by SQLAlchemy it feels more precise.