# What are drawbacks of automatic rollbacks in case of exceptions?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

When you write a flask+sqlalchemy app and make a DB query + Exception handling like this:

```py
def add_user(user: User) -> bool:  # was the user added?
    errors = []
    try:
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception:  # e.g. Integrity error
        return False
```

It can later show `PendingRollbackError`. A solution I've used in a couple of projects is [proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33284980/562769):

```py
@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    if exception:
        db.session.rollback()
    db.session.remove()
```

What are the disadvantages of this solution? If it doesn't have any, I wonder why this is not done by default.

Comment: Hi Martin. I haven't used Flask in a while, but the proposed solution ensures that the db session is closed at the end of the request. AFAIK, if you use the Flask-Sqlalchemy library, it automatically does add a hook to `teardown_request`

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of the Flask-Sqlalchemy stuff, it couples the web app and the data layer too tightly in my opinion.